# How can I set the default value in a SharePoint list field, based on the value in another field?

Tags: sharepoint

I have a custom list in SharePoint (specifically, MOSS 2007.) One field is a yes/no checkbox titled "Any defects?" Another field is "Closed by" and names the person who has closed the ticket.

If there are no defects then I want the ticket to be auto-closed. If there are, then the "Closed by" field ought to be filled in later on.

I figured I could set a calculated default value for "Closed by" like this:

```
=IF([Any defects?],"",[Me])
```

but SharePoint complains I have referenced a field. I suppose this makes sense; the default values fire when the new list item is first opened for entry and there are no values in any fields yet.

I understand it is possible to make a calculated field based on a column value but in that case the field cannot be edited later.

Does anyone have any advice how to achieve what I am trying to do?

Is it possible to have a "OnSubmit" type event that allows me to execute some code at the point the list item is saved?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Include a content editor web part in the page (newform.aspx / editform.aspx) and use jQuery (or just plain javascript) to handle the setting of default values.

Edit: some example code:

In the lists newform.aspx, include a reference to jquery. If you look at the html code, you can see that each input tag gets an id based on the field's GUID, and a title that's set to the fields display name.

now, using jquery we can get at these fields using the jQuery selector like this:

By title:

```
$("input[title='DISPLAYNAMEOFFIELD']");
```

by id (if you know the field's internal guid, the dashes will ahve to be replaced by underscores:

```
// example field id, notice the guid and the underscores in the guid ctl00_m_g_054db6a0_0028_412d_bdc1_f2522ac3922e_ctl00_ctl04_ctl15_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_TextField

$("input[id*='GUID']"); //this will get all input elements of which the id contains the specified GUID, i.e. 1 element
```

We wrap this in the `ready()` function of jQuery, so all calls will only be made when the document has fully loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 // enter code here, will be executed immediately after page has been loaded
});
```

By combining these 2 we could now set your dropdown's `onchange` event to the following

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("input[title='DISPLAYNAMEOFFIELD']").change(function() 
 {
      //do something to other field here 
 });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the advice to use JavaScript and how to embed it.

Would it be possible to trouble you slightly further for some sample code? Can I refer to fields in the list as JavaScript variables?

Thanks !

Comment: Much appreciated! I will be sure to come back and vote your answer up when I have 15 reputation points!

Comment: No problem! glad to be of help

Comment: Nice! When you get time to edit answers you give some good stuff.

Comment: @Alex; Doing this in the boss's time :-P

Comment: Woohoo, I now have > 15 rep so +1 to you :)

Comment: Small update for anyone else reading this. A separate document ready wrapper is not needed if you use $('your_element') as this format is a shorthand for document ready.

Answer (score 1):

The [Use jQuery to Set A Text Field’s Value on a SharePoint Form](http://www.endusersharepoint.com/?p=1756) article on EndUserSharePoint.com shows you how to set a default value for a field using JavaScript/jQuery.

They also have a whole series of articles on ['taming calculated columns'](http://www.endusersharepoint.com/?s=taming+calculated+column) that will show you many more powerful options you have for calculated fields with the use of jQuery.

One thing to be aware of when inserting JavaScript into a SharePoint page and modifying the DOM is support. There is a small chance that a future service pack will break the functionality you add, and it is quite likely that the next version of SharePoint will break it. Keeping this mind however, I believe it's a good solution at this time.

Comment: Thanks so much, I appreciate the help. Now I can get back into code I feel much more positive about bending SharePoint to my will!! I will come back and upvote you when I have 15 reputation.

Comment: Woohoo, I now have > 15 rep so +1 to you :)

Answer (score 0):

I've got a walk through with sample code that may help

- [Setting a default duration for new calendar events](http://blog.pentalogic.net/2009/09/setting-default-duration-for-new-calender-events/)

It sets the End Time/Date fields to Start Time + 1.5 hours when you create a new event.

Its complicated a little by the steps need to do the time/date work, but you'll see examples of how to find the elements on the form and also one way to get your script onto the newform.aspx without using SPD.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  // Set the hours to add - can be over 24
  var hoursToAdd = 1;
  // Mins must be 0 or div by 5, e.g. 0, 5, 10, 15 ...
  var minutesToAdd = 30;

  // JavaScript assumes dates in US format (MM/DD/YYYY)
  // Set to true to use dates in format DD/MM/YYYY
  var bUseDDMMYYYYformat = false;

  $(function() {

    // Find the start and end time/minutes dropdowns by first finding the
    // labels then using the for attribute to find the id's
    // NOTE - You will have to change this if your form uses non-standard
    // labels and/or non-english language packs
    var cboStartHours = $("#" + $("label:contains('Start Time Hours')").attr("for"));
    var cboEndHours = $("#" + $("label:contains('End Time Hours')").attr("for"));
    var cboEndMinutes = $("#" + $("label:contains('End Time Minutes')").attr("for"));

    // Set Hour
    var endHour = cboStartHours.attr("selectedIndex") + hoursToAdd;
    cboEndHours.attr("selectedIndex",endHour % 24);

    // If we have gone over the end of a day then change date
    if ((endHour / 24)>=1)
    {
        var txtEndDate = $("input[title='End Time']");
        var dtEndDate = dtParseDate(txtEndDate.val());
        if (!isNaN(dtEndDate))
        {
            dtEndDate.setDate( dtEndDate.getDate() + (endHour / 24));
            txtEndDate.val(formatDate(dtEndDate));
        }
    }

    // Setting minutes is easy!
    cboEndMinutes.val(minutesToAdd);    

});

// Some utility functions for parsing and formatting - could use a library
// such as www.datejs.com instead of this
function dtParseDate(sDate)
{
    if (bUseDDMMYYYYformat)
    {
        var A = sDate.split(/[\\\/]/);
        A = [A[1],A[0],A[2]];
        return new Date(A.join('/'));
    }
    else
        return new Date(sDate);
}

function formatDate(dtDate)
{
    if (bUseDDMMYYYYformat)
        return dtDate.getDate() + "/" + dtDate.getMonth()+1 + "/" + dtDate.getFullYear();
    else
        return dtDate.getMonth()+1 + "/" + dtDate.getDate() + "/" + dtDate.getFullYear();
}

</script>
```