# Sharepoint date range formula

Tags: sharepoint, date, formula

I am creating a holiday request site and need to find the best way to update users holiday entitlements when the date range includes a bank holiday.   Currently when users create a new request with a [START TIME] of say 29th Aug and [End TIME] of 4 September the total number of holidays will be incorrect as it will also include the Aug bank holiday. The column creates a total number of days to be deducted from the users holiday entitlements. I want a formula to check the date range and exclude any bank holidays from the total.  Any help will be much appreciated.  Damo

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately SharePoint's calculated column functionality isn't particularly advanced. However have a look at this Pentalogic blog post [Working Days, Weekdays and Holidays in SharePoint Calculated Columns](http://blog.pentalogic.net/2008/11/working-days-weekdays-holidays-sharepoint-calculated-columns/) which might give you some tips.

If you find you have to go down the route of custom code, have a look at the SO question [How can I set the default value in a SharePoint list field, based on the value in another field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090274/how-can-i-set-the-default-value-in-a-sharepoint-list-field-based-on-the-value-in) This shows how you can use JavaScript (specifically jQuery) to update a SharePoint field with a more advanced calculation.