# Sharepoint custom list, dynamic field?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, moss

Hey guys, just wondering if their is a simple way to create an Item in a custom list but i need that item to be dynamic. The user can click add more to get another field that would hold the same type of data an unlimited amount of time.

If i could even just add an excel spreadsheet type of field that would work also. But excel wouldnt need to be a requirement on the users machine.

I thought i had read somewhere you could do this using info path but i cant seem to find anything relating to it on google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The InfoPath feature is called a "repeating section". There is information on how to set that up in [Office Online](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/infopath/HA011378071033.aspx).

If you wanted to achieve this entirely in SharePoint, the problem is that there can only be a fixed number of fields in a list. So you could create as many that would ever be used and just display all of those. Or to make it much nicer for the user incorporate jQuery to hide all of the fields except the first one and provide a button for them to click that unhides the next one.

There is good information on how to access list form fields using jQuery in the question [How can I set the default value in a SharePoint list field, based on the value in another field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090274/how-can-i-set-the-default-value-in-a-sharepoint-list-field-based-on-the-value-in)